# Generalized version of Weierstrass M-Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $(V_1, \lVert \cdot \rVert_{V_1})$ be a normed vector space and $(V_1, \lVert \cdot \rVert_{V_2})$ be a complete normed vector space. Let $(C_b(V_1, V_2), \lVert\cdot\rVert)$ be the vector space of all continuous bounded functions $f:V_1\to V_2$. Prove this version of the Weierstrass M-Test:

> If $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence in $C_b(V_1, V_2)$ where $\lVert\ f_k \rVert_\infty\le M_k$ for all $k$, and $\left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n M_k \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty M_k$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then $\left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n f_k \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty f_k$ uniformly.

But isn't it always the case that, even if $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty M_k$ is divergent, $\left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n M_k \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ will converge to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty M_k$? I seem to misunderstand what exactly this statement means. Or maybe this statement is lacking some details?

I will, nevertheless, try to prove this (making my own interpretation of the statement above).

I'm not sure how to prove this statement. Would appreciate some basic outline.

Comment: I think if V1,V2 are general complete metric space and you define the space C_b(V1,V2) of bounded continuous functions from V1 to V2 by sup norm, then you can show that C_b(V1,V2) is complete and Weierstrass M test holds.

Comment: Yes, I know that $C_b$ is complete, but I don't know what to do next...

Comment: Well, then the sequence of function s_n=f1+f2+...+fn forms a Cauchy sequence so it must converge.

Comment: @Ben, can you please explain what it means  that $\left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n M_k \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty M_k$? Isn't it always the case that, even if $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty M_k$ is divergent, $\left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n M_k \right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ will converge to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty M_k$? I don't understand what this notation in the statement of the question means.

Comment: @sequence No, if that series is divergent then the sequence of partial sums in divergent, although we often use $\to \infty$ notation. All they're saying is $\sum M_n < \infty.$ Not sure why the problem is stated in that weird way.